# How to reduce the time complexity of convert vector to mat

Tags: java, android, algorithm, opencv, time-complexity

I tried to convert from long vector with size 259,920 to mat of 361 X 720 (The same concept as vect2mat in matlab).The code is work,but when I tried it on HTC phone,takes one second to response. So, what I can change or use to obtain good result with less time. The following code that I use.

```
public static Mat vect2mat( double[] array, int a) {
Mat matrix = new Mat(a,(array.length+a-1)/a, CvType.CV_8UC1);
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<(array.length+a-1)/a; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<a; j++){
        matrix.put(j,i,array[count]);
        count++;
    }
}
return matrix;
```

}

Comment: You can probably create the matrix from the array, and then reshape: `Mat tmp = new Mat(1, array.length, CvType.CV_8UC1); tmp.put(0,0,array); return tmp.reshape(1, a);`. Please let me know, as I can't test Java code. I will write as an answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

THIS CODE BELOW IS NOT TESTED (especially, array indexing)!!!

But its idea is to use `System.arraycopy` to quickly copy parts of one-dimensional array to a 2-dimensional array. And then, assign the array to Mat because a Mat can put the whole array at the same time (using 1 loop) rather than put one by one.

Try this sample code:

```
public static Mat vect2mat( double[] array, int a) {
    Mat matrix = new Mat(a,(array.length+a-1)/a, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    int count = 0;
    double[][] matArray = new double[a][(array.length+a-1)/a];
    for(int i=0; i<(array.length+a-1)/a; i++){
        System.arraycopy(array, a*i, matArray[][i], 0, a);
        matrix.put(a*i,i,array[][i]);//put the whole array
    }
    return matrix;
}
```